# Is there a way to receive data as unsigned char over UDP on Qt?

Tags: qt, udp

I need to send floating point numbers using a [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) connection to a [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) application. Now in Qt the only function available is

```
qint64 readDatagram ( char * data, qint64 maxSize, QHostAddress * address = 0, quint16 * port = 0 )
```

which accepts data in the form of signed character buffer. I can convert my float into a string and send it but it will obviously not be very efficient converting a 4 byte float into a much longer sized character buffer.

I got hold of these 2 functions to convert a 4 byte float into an unsinged 32 bit integer to transfer over network which works fine for a simple C++ UDP program but for Qt I need to receive the data as unsigned char.

Is it possible to avoid converting the floatinf point data into a string and then sending it?

```
uint32_t htonf(float f)
{
    uint32_t p;
    uint32_t sign;

    if (f < 0) { sign = 1; f = -f; }
    else { sign = 0; }

    p = ((((uint32_t)f)&0x7fff)<<16) | (sign<<31); // Whole part and sign.
    p |= (uint32_t)(((f - (int)f) * 65536.0f))&0xffff; // Fraction.

    return p;
}

float ntohf(uint32_t p)
{
    float f = ((p>>16)&0x7fff); // Whole part.
    f += (p&0xffff) / 65536.0f; // Fraction.

    if (((p>>31)&0x1) == 0x1) { f = -f; } // Sign bit set.

    return f;
}
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned why you need conversion at all. Is this a heterogenous network application or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the downvote, since the question is vague in requirements.

A 4-byte float is simply a 4 character buffer, if cast as one. If the systems are homogenous, the float can be sent as a signed char *, and bit for bit it'll be the same read into the signed char * on the receiver directly, no conversion needed. If the systems are heterogenous, then this won't work and you need to convert it to a portable format, anyway. IEEE format is often used, but my question is still, what are the requirements, is the float format the same between systems?

Comment: I am really sorry for the downvote. I dont know I was thinking on some crap lines. It was actually pretty simple just as u said i could obviously treat a signed char as an unsigned char. I accepted the message in a char array and generated an unsigned 32 bit int from it by bit shifting and all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `readDatagram`? Or converting the data to a [`QByteArray`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-3) after reading?  In many cases a `char*` is really just a byte array.  This is one of those cases. Note that the [`writeDatagram`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram-2) can take a QByteArray.

Generally every thing sent across sockets is in bytes not strings, layers on either end do the conversions.  Take a look [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qudpsocket.html#details), especially the Broadcaster examples.  They show how to create a `QByteArray` for broadcast and receive.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, your primary question seems to be how to receive data of type `unsigned char` with QT's `readDatagram` function which uses a pointer to a buffer of type `char`.

The short answer is use a cast along these lines:

```
const size_t MAXSIZE = 1024;
unsigned char* data = malloc(MAXSIZE);

readDatagram ( (unsigned char *)data, MAXSIZE, address, port )
```

I'm going to assume you have multiple machines which use the same IEEE floating point format but some of which are big endian and some of which are little endian.  [See this SO post for a good discussion of this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873352/how-do-i-convert-a-value-from-host-byte-order-to-little-endian).

In that case you could do something a bit simpler like this:

```
const size_t FCOUNT = 256;
float* data = malloc(FCOUNT * sizeof(*data));

readDatagram ( (char *)data, FCOUNT * sizeof(*data), address, port )

for (int i = 0; i != FCOUNT; ++i)
    data[i] = ntohf(*((uint32_t*)&data[i]));
```

The thing to remember is that as far as networking functions like `readDatagram` are concerned, the data is just a bunch of bits and it doesn't care what type those bits are interpreted as.

Answer (score 0):

If both ends of your UDP connection use Qt, I would suggest looking at QDataStream. You can create this from a QByteArray each time you read a datagram, and then read whatever values you require - floats, maps, lists, QVariants, and of course string.

Similarly, on the sending side, you'd create a data stream, push data into it, then send the resulting QByteArray over writeDatagram.

Obviously this only works if both ends use Qt - the data encoding is well-defined, but non-trivial to generate by hand.

(If you want stream orientated behaviour, you could use the fact that QUDPSocket is a QIODevice with a data-stream, but it sounds as if you want per-datagram behaviour)