# Convert uint64_t to 8 byte little endian long

Tags: c++

I have a variable called length that is of type uint64_t. I want to convert it to 8 byte little endian long and I'm very confused about these data types.

Can someone guide me on how to make this conversion?

Comment: First convert to 64-bit unsigned. Then [convert as necessary to little endian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873352/how-do-i-convert-a-value-from-host-byte-order-to-little-endian).

Comment: The diagrams at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness might be helpful.

Comment: memcpy to unsigned char array and then swap as necessary. memcpy to your destination.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I'm afraid that `uint64-t` is already unsigned, no need to convert it to unsigned again.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Oh, thanks. I was mislead by the "convert ... to unsigned" in the question title  and main text. Fixing. But, now it's a duplicate. Closing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is [Boost.Endian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0_b1/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html).

```
#include <boost/endian/conversion.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int main() {
   std::uint64_t foo = 1;
   std::cout << boost::endian::endian_reverse(foo);
}
```

Output: `72057594037927936`